# Dynamic report export file name (PBI Paginated Reports)

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

Is it possible to add a dynamic extension to the name of a report export (Excel, PDF etc.)?

More specifically, when sending the Excel export of a report to a subscirber, the filename should be supplemented with the execution date.

**Example**

Report Name: Report_A

The subscriber receives a mail with the Excel file: Report_A_20230824

It is possible to tag the worksheets of an Excel with this information but does it also work with the filename?